# Uma função que recebe como argumentos os nomes de dois arquivos

Tags: python, funções, lista, arquivo, argumento

Programa contendo uma função que recebe como argumentos os nomes de dois arquivos. O primeiro arquivo contém nomes de alunos e o segundo arquivo contém as notas dos alunos. No primeiro arquivo, cada linha corresponde ao nome de um aluno e no segundo arquivo, cada linha corresponde às notas dos alunos (uma ou mais). Assuma que as notas foram armazenadas como string, e estão separadas umas das outras por espaços em branco. Leia os dois arquivos e gere um terceiro arquivo que contém o nome do aluno seguido da média de suas notas.

Eu comecei assim:

```
lista= []

with open('arquivo1linha.txt', 'a') as file:
        novo = "\n"+input("ALUNO 1: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("ALUNO 2: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("ALUNO 3: ")
        file.write(novo)
      
with open('arquivo2linha.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
        novo = "\n"+input("NOTA 1: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("NOTA 2: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("NOTA 3: ")
        arquivo.write(novo)
     
file = open('arquivo1linha.txt', 'r')
file.readlines()
['primeira linha\n', 'segunda linha\n', 'terceira linha\n',]
file.readlines()
file.close()
   
arquivo = open('arquivo2linha.txt', 'r')
arquivo.readlines()
['primeira linha\n', 'segunda linha\n', 'terceira linha\n',]
arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()

linha_arquivo_3 = arquivo1linha[]+ " " + arquivo2linha[]
    print (linha_arquivo_3)


print("Número de linhas: ", len(file.read))
print("Número de linhas: ", len(arquivo.read))
```

Não consigo prosseguir

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolve, só adicionei/renomeie algumas variaves, mas a parte do codigo para gerar os arquivo são os mesmos da pergunta

```
lista= []

def countAluno(fAluno = 'aluno.txt'):
    with open(fAluno) as f:
        i = 0
        for line in f:
            i += 1
    return i

with open('aluno.txt', 'a') as file:
        novo = input("ALUNO 1: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("ALUNO 2: ")
        novo += "\n"+input("ALUNO 3: ")
        file.write(novo)
        file.close()
        
fAluno = open('aluno.txt', 'r')
alunos = fAluno.readlines()
fAluno.close()
    
      
with open('nota.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
    for n in range(countAluno()):
        print(alunos[n])
        novo = input("NOTA 1: ")
        novo += " "+input("NOTA 2: ")
        novo += " "+input("NOTA 3: ") + "\n"
        arquivo.write(novo)
    arquivo.close()
        
fNota = open('nota.txt', 'r')
notas = fNota.readlines()
fNota.close()

def calculoMedia(arqAluno='aluno.txt',  arqNota= 'nota.txt'):
    
    fAluno = open(arqAluno, 'r')
    alunos = fAluno.readlines()
    fAluno.close()

    fNota = open(arqNota, 'r')
    notas = fNota.readlines()
    fNota.close()
    
    for n in range(countAluno()):
        aluno = alunos[n].replace('\n', '')
        nota = notas[n].replace('\n', '').split(' ')
        valor = [int(val) for val in nota]
        lista.append([aluno,valor])
        
    with open('media.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
        for n in range(len(lista)):
            aluno = lista[n][0]
            media = sum(lista[n][1])/3
            arquivo.write(aluno +' '+str(media)+'\n')
        arquivo.close()

calculoMedia()
```

Comment: Muito obrigada. Valeu